# how to remove decimals in rownames matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix like that:

```
                      12Q_S12   14Q_S14    16Q_S16     18Q_S2     22Q_S6    28Q_S12     
ENSG00000000003.14    1.18007    0.0000    1.20602    2.24477    1.27663    1.12392   
ENSG00000000005.5     0.00000    0.0000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000
```

and I would like to remove the decimal part only for the rownames (ENSG00000000003.14, ENSG00000000005.5 ...) any help?

Expected:

```
                       12Q_S12   14Q_S14    16Q_S16     18Q_S2     22Q_S6    28Q_S12     
    ENSG00000000003    1.18007    0.0000    1.20602    2.24477    1.27663    1.12392   
    ENSG00000000005     0.00000    0.0000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Have you tried anything? please include a reproducible example with your question (use `dput`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reassign the `rownames` and eliminate the part after the point, you can do it with `gsub`.

```
rownames(tab) <- gsub("\\..*","",rownames(tab))
```

Comment: yes it works perfectly! thanks for the answer and for the nice explanation!